# Drag and Drop functionality using testcomplete

Tags: vbscript, devexpress, automated-tests, xtragrid, testcomplete

I want to simulate a **drag and drop functionality** from **one DevXtraGridcell to  another** DevXtraGridcell without using the coordinate system.

Can someone give me an idea how can I do it without the default record and play and without the source and destination cordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Drag`](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/60240/) action always uses coordinates, but you can calculate the coordinates on the fly instead of using hard-coded coordinates:

1. Explore your grid in TestComplete's Object Browser and find a method or property that returns cell coordinates. 
   According to [this old blog post](http://blog.smartbear.com/software-quality/selecting-cells-in-developer-express-xtragrid/), it should be something like:

   ```
   gridObj.MainView.ViewInfo.RowsInfo.GetInfoByHandle(Row).Cells.Item_2(Column).Bounds
   ```
2. Calculate the coordinates of the first and second cell. (Make sure that both cells are visible on the screen.)
3. Do the `Drag` from one first cell's coordiantes to the second cell's coordinates.

Comment: i tried using the mainview.viewinfo.... but i am getting an object does not support this property error.. and Viewinfo is not present in the inbuilt library function too....

Comment: We don't have this function in Testcomplete 10 any other solution would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

in my case i had to user the obj.MainView.get_ViewInfo property worked for one gridcontrol , the other is of card layout the link given doesnt work in my case though